# Simple Animation Issue Xcode 7 Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, uiimage

I can't seem to make a simple fade-in fade-out animation in Xcode.

All I want to do is make an image fade in 2 seconds after the viewDidLoad (which works fine), but once I add code for the fade out animation the image is never initially hidden.

Here is my code:

```
image.alpha = 0


UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 2, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.image.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 3, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.image.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
```

I am using UIImages for the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply chaining `UIView.animateWithDuration` animations in the same scope like that is problematic. A way to achieve the effect you described would be to call the second animation in the completion block of the first one, like so

```
self.image.alpha = 0

UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 2, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
    self.image.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { finished in

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.image.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
})
```

Edit: this doesn't directly relate to the problem you're describing, but just to add a bit of general advice based on the wording of your question: it's usually better to start initial timed animations in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods of your view controller. `viewDidLoad` getting called does not necessarily mean that the view is being displayed right away, which might throw your timing off (especially if your view gets more complex with regard to memory and resources).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 2, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
    self.image.alpha = 1
    }, completion: {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 3, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.image.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
})
```

**Simple Rule: Wait for one animation to complete before you start off with other. You were executing them back to back that was resulting first one in no effect state.**